# Multi-line titles break the synchronization in reledmac / reledpar

Tags: double-sided, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

**TL;DR In a parallel type setting environment using reledmac / reledpar, when titles on one side are longer (more lines) than on the other side, the synchronization breaks.**

I am currently creating a Latex document in a twoside class which contains a bilingual text: On the left side (the left page) there is always a latin text and on the right side (the right page) there is the german translation. For this I am using reledpar. I have stanzas (astanza) on the left side and the translation on the right side and I always let a headline / title preceed the actual stanza / translation.

I add the title as a parameter to the astanza environment which is therefore passed on to the pstart, because astanza is just a special wrapper of pstart / pend.

The problem I now have is that if the title on one side is longer (spans over more lines than the title on the other side) the synchronization is off. It looks like it does not count for the multiple lines in the title and syncs the other side as if it would be just a one line title. The same thing also happens when using **pstart / pend** directly and not using **astanza**.
[image: Long titles break synchronization]
[Long titles break synchronization PDF](https://mega.nz/#!ZyhTXIBI!6eD1FieVjwXyPj_PrFMa7CJp6s2k9aocQz8ObxiUbXE)

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

 % Set stanza indentation
\setstanzaindents{0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}

\begin{document}
    \large
        \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart[I have long titles on both sides, but sometimes the title on one side is bigger than the one on the other side]
                    verse  verse verse 1!
                    verse verse verse 2!
                    verse verse verse 3!
                    verse  verse verse 1!
                \pend
                \pstart[Just a normal title]
                    verse  verse verse 1
                    verse verse verse 2!
                    verse verse verse 3!
                    verse  verse verse 1!
                \pend
            \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[Just a normal title]
                This is a translation paragraph
            \pend
            \pstart[Just a normal title]
                This is a translation paragraph
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it is basically another question, but while working at this the question came up to me if it is possible to center the stanzas using astanza without breaking the indentation provided by this?
The result should be the same indentation, but every stanza itself is centered on the page regarding on its line length.

Comment: Change the question and don't add a comment. Better: Ask a new question if it's a new question.

Comment: That is also what I thought. I will ask that question again in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a known bug of reledpar. For now, I have no time to look on. You can add `\\~` on your shorter title.